# Non-diagonal elements when switching metric signature?

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus, metric-tensor

Considering a metric tensor with the signature $(-,+,+,+)$:

$g_{\mu\nu}=
\begin{pmatrix}
-c^2 & g_{01} & g_{02} & g_{03}\\
g_{10} & a^2 & g_{12} & g_{13}\\
g_{20} & g_{21} & a^2 & g_{23}\\
g_{30} & g_{31} & g_{32} & a^2\\
\end{pmatrix}$

If I switch the signature to $(+,-,-,-)$, what is the form of the new tensor ?
$g_{\mu\nu}=
\begin{pmatrix}
c^2 & ? & ? & ?\\
? & -a^2 & ? & ?\\
? & ? & -a^2 & ?\\
? & ? & ? & -a^2\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You multiply  the whole metric tensor by a factor of $-1$.